# Search Function for Favourites

Tags: feature-request

Recently I tried to go through my favourites for a question on rings. I can't remember when I added it, and realised that there is no search function apart from the sorting tabs above. Can a search function be implemented for my favourites?

Thanks,

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3683/148396

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We used to have this functionality, but lost it due to technical reasons when we upgraded search to Lucene.NET about 6 months ago.

FWIW, I do support this request, it has just become technically hard to accomplish.