# Managing favourites

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, bookmarks

I'm a new user but my favourites are already becoming a bit cumbersome to go through. I imagine they may become completely unmanageable in a year's time. I was wondering if it would be possible to sort those questions by their tags. I've read [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3477/search-function-for-favourites) that implementing a search functionality is technically difficult. Would it be easier to allow some sort of tag-sorting or tag-searching?

(If it's already possible, could you please tell me how to do it?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tips for organizing one's own favorites?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3251/tips-for-organizing-ones-own-favorites)

Comment: @Asaf a feature-request can hardly be called a duplicate of discussion of what methods are available now

Comment: @Grigory: I should probably refrain from suggesting duplicates before completely waking up. :-)

Comment: +1. Nice Question. I am interested too. I see 2 votes to close. I think it won't materialize to close the post! We need to come up with some way of maintaining our favourites, some w'd like to go through at a later time, our long answers, so that we could quote them in our later answers!