# Could bookmarks have a facility for grouping questions similar to playlists in YouTube?

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

As a user, I have a need to explore a variety of topics simultaneously for academic reasons. With time the bookmarks of questions of my interest started becoming a bit cumbersome, haphazard and all over the place. I was thinking the high value we get as YouTube users by being able to group videos in playlists of niche themes or as twitter user to create lists of accounts with niche identities, could be replicated here. I guess tags would be more similar to YouTube topics.
Since this feature is prevalent on many platforms, I'm guessing maybe it is intrinsically very rewarding to the end-user.
As a representative user of possibly a segment/persona of users on the site, some of my personal "playlists" that I am genuinely interested to follow would be "infinite products involving factorials", "mean value theorems applied on polynomials", "gems of ingenuity" etc. Please consider this feature request.

Comment: Welcome to Math meta SE. FYI, a couple of related general Meta question are [Could we have lists within favorites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289585) and [Add a feature that allows the user to divide their bookmarks into different groups](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371719).

Comment: Another related post on [meta.se]: [Favorites improvements - search, categorize, personal tags, add note, favorite answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75944) (and other [posts linked there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/75944)). On this meta: [Are there any functions to search with keywords or categorize my thousands of bookmarked questions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32603) and the [posts linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/32603).

Comment: For example, these two feature requests look similar: [Multiple Favourites Lists](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26399) and [Organizing favorite posts in folders\categories](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28907)

Comment: This could be handled with personalized tagging, which I think is a great idea, and I am not holding my breath.

Comment: This was recently announced: [Bookmarks Are Evolving Into Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019). The planned feature seems similar to this feature request.

Answer (score 1):

I began keeping an ordinary text   file (on my home desktop) I named Topics.txt

It is mostly urls of questions or specific answers I thought were interesting, grouped by by common themes according to my view of things.

One part I had not necessarily   predicted was my ability to paste in several lines from that file, as examples of the techniques in my answers. One that comes up regularly is solving $p^x - q^y = C,$  positive integers and $p,q$  prime. I have about 15 lines on that topic in my file. The most impressive one I was able to finish was  [Finding solutions to the diophantine equation $7^a=3^b+100$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1946621/finding-solutions-to-the-diophantine-equation-7a-3b100/1946810#1946810)